# How can I remove part of a url after a specific keyword?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, url-rewriting

For example:

```
example.com/fun/browse/apples/bananas

example.com/browse/gerbals/cooties
```

How can I find the keyword "browse", regardless of where it is in the url, and remove the following url part. In the above cases that would be "apples" and "gerbals"

I tried spliting it by the "/" and getting the indexOf browse, then removing the next item, but I cant seem to join everything together because that creates a double "//" in the new url.

Any help would be appreciated.

Javascript and jQuery both ok.

NOTE: I do not want to remove any other part of the url. I want to keep everything. I want to only remove the part of the url immediately after browse.

Comment: Paste code which you have tried, Even better a jsfiddle

Comment: Do you want to remove /fun/ part too? Specify what is the effect you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Satpal, I haven't gotten much of anywhere other than getting the url, splitting it, and getting the index of Browse.

Comment: @Szymon I only want to remove the part immediately after browse, I don't want to remove any other part of the link.

Comment: You should add the desired result : "example.com/fun/browse/apples/bananas" > "example.com/fun/browse/bananas"?

Comment: @Noah - I have updated my answer according to your requirement. take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19733394/489512

Answer (score 1):

remove browser by using .splice() & rejoin it.

```
var arr = "example.com/fun/browse/apples/bananas".split('/'); 
var index = arr.indexOf("browse"); 
arr.splice(index+1,1); //removes apples
var URL = arr.join('/'); //joins back

result: "example.com/fun/browse/bananas"
```

Comment: that's not the result

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear but let's try :

```
var s = 'example.com/fun/browse/apples/bananas';
s.replace(/(\/browse)\/[^\/]+/, '$1'); // "example.com/fun/browse/bananas"
```

Also check this helper :

```
function removeAfter(s, keyword) {
    return s.replace(
        new RegExp('(\/' + keyword + ')\/[^\/]+'), '$1'
    );
}
```

Usage :

```
var s = 'example.com/browse/gerbals/cooties';
removeAfter(s, 'browse'); // "example.com/browse/cooties"
removeAfter(s, 'gerbals'); // "example.com/browse/gerbals"
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/VRJtL/.

Comment: @Noah This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @Noah So, override the variable if needed : `s = s.replace(...)`.

Comment: @Noah Answer and demo updated. I've added a reusable function.

Answer (score 0):

Split the URL on the Keyword...

example:

```
var url = "http://www.foo.com/bar/alpha/beta";
var keyword = "alpha";
var result = url.split(keyword)[0];
//result = "http://www.foo.com/bar/" + keyword;

//adding the keyword is if you need the keyword in your response.
```

Comment: My goal isn't to remove the rest of the url, just the part immediately after

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to remove 'fun' part, it's really simple:

```
var url = 'example.com/fun/browse/apples/bananas';
var result = url.replace(/browse\/[a-zA-Z\/]+/, 'browse/gerbals/cooties');
```

Comment: This requires me to know the 2nd part of the replace() and I was hoping for something a bit more dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw out another option, just to make it interesting.   :)

```
var url = "http://example.com/fun/browse/apples/bananas";
var targetWord = "browse";
var regexPattern = new RegExp("(^.*" + targetWord + "/?)[^/]*/?(.*$)");
var newURL = "";

var matchedURLparts = regexPattern.exec(url); 
if (matchedURLparts) {
    newURL = (matchedURLparts.length > 2) ? matchedURLparts[1] + matchedURLparts[2] : matchedURLparts[1];
}
else {
    newURL = url;
}
```

Comment: This removes everything after browse which is not intended. I only want to remove the part immediately after.

Comment: Sorry . . . I misunderstood what you were asking to have removed.  I've updated it with code that will work.

Comment: One more update, to allow for a few extra possible string inputs.

Comment: Aaaaaand one more change to make it even more flexible.   :D